# C# Process is Terminated due to StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#

This is my code. Running time increases memory usage until it stops due to this error:

> Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KillWW
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting... {0} ", DateTime.Now);
            killWinword();
           // Console.Read();
        }

        private static void killWinword()
        {
            var procs = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (var proc in procs)
            {
                if (proc.ProcessName == "WINWORD")
                {
                    TimeSpan runtime;
                    runtime = DateTime.Now - proc.StartTime;

                    if (DateTime.Now > proc.StartTime.AddSeconds(20))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            killWinword();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what the cause of it is? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have a recursive call without stop condition. So it's an infinite recursion. This will end up in Stackoverflow. It seems you want to do a check every second. You can use a Timer to do that.

Comment: What is use of calling `killWinword();` inside the `for-loop`? Simply remove that statement

Comment: @SouvikGhosh It's not inside the for.

Comment: [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3f4f460-7d35-4406-b427-9c77bbbe6b55/repeating-tasks?forum=tpldataflow) is a solution using async/await Tasks.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry I meant after the loop.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I guess he was trying to make it repeat the check every second. He seems to be unaware of the sideeffects of recursion ...

Comment: @user3194852 In such case I would rather use a timer.. and every 1 second run the method, eventually checking if is still running from the previous call, and only starting if not..

Comment: @Fildor That's right. It could have been done using a timer

Comment: Thanks all. I want show console overtime not using Console.ReadLine(); or Console.Read(); or Console.ReadKey();. Please help me.

Comment: How would you like it to be exited then?

Comment: See my updated example. It works without Read() or ReadLine(). It will wait for Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thank @Fildor and everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a recursive call without stop condition. ( `killWinword` calls `killWinword`, which calls `killWinword` ... )

So it's an **infinite recursion.** Each new call will take up more space on the stack. This will sooner or later end up in Stackoverflow.

It seems you want to do a check every second. You can:

- Use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that ticks every second.
- Use a Task and async/await ( See [Example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3f4f460-7d35-4406-b427-9c77bbbe6b55/repeating-tasks?forum=tpldataflow) )
- Use a plain old Thread to execute the check in a loop, so your main Thread won't get blocked.

(No specific order. I'd personally go for async/await but the other solutions are also valid for this simple and short program).

Caveat of Timer would be that you'd have to check if the last invocation is still running. Advantage of Task is you can easily make use of the Threadpool.

Example:

```
    // Run-Flag to gracefully exit loop.
    private static volatile bool _keepRunning = true;
    private static ManualResetEvent _exitRequest = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting... {0} ", DateTime.Now);
        Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MainClass._keepRunning = false;
        };            

        Task.Run(() => KillWinword); // Start Task on ThreadPool
        //You don't want to use Console.Read(); So ... wait for Ctrl-C?
        _exitRequest.WaitOne();
    }

    private static async Task KillWinword()
    {
        try
        {
            // Loop instead of recursion
            while(_keepRunning)
            {
                // Do your checks here
                DoKillWinword();

                // Don't delay if exit is requested.
                if(_keepRunning) await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
        _exitRequest.Set();
        }
    }

    private static void DoKillWinword()
    {
        // TIPP: You should add some Exception handling in here!

        var procs = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (var proc in procs)
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName == "WINWORD")
            {
                TimeSpan runtime;
                runtime = DateTime.Now - proc.StartTime;

                if (DateTime.Now > proc.StartTime.AddSeconds(20))
                {
                    proc.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Mind that this will not exactly start the check every second. It will start a new check 1 second after the previous one is done.

Answer (score 3):

Last line of KillWinWord is calling itself. So each second (after the sleep) you add a new layer on the stack.

If you want the kill feature to last forever, replace the recursive call by a while loop.

Comment: That will block the main thread, though. Not sure if that matters here.